# Which Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphism with $B(E)$ for some Banach space $E$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Consider $H$ as a Hilbert space. How can I find a Banach space $E$, for that, $H=B(E)$ where $B(E)$ is the set of bounded linear operator on $E$?
(At least under some conditions on $H$)

Also if the Hilbert space $H$ is Banach algebra, when we can find a Banach space $E$, such that $H$ is a Banach-algebra-isomorphism isometric with some Banach subalgebra of $B(E)$?

Comment: Do you want to have $H= B(E)$ only as sets or do you want the norms to coincide? If so, $E$ will have to be a Hilbert space. Indeed, fix a linear functional $\varphi \in E'$ with $\Vert \varphi \Vert = 1$ and consider the operator $A_z : e \mapsto \varphi(e) \cdot z$ for $z \in E$. It is not hard to see $\Vert A_z \Vert = \Vert z \Vert$, so that $E \to B(E), z \mapsto A_z$ is an isometric isomorphism. But $B(E)$ is a Hilbert space, so that $E$ is isometric to a closed subspace of a Hilbert space and thus a Hilbert space.

Comment: @PhoemueX The title says "Isometric". So $E$ is a Hilbert space. But if $E$ is a Hilbert space $B(E)$ is not a Hilbert space, is it? Ah, no it's not: for example $B(E)$ has a subalgebra, hence subspace, isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^\infty$. The norm on that subspace does not satisfy the parallelogram thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Nice idea! Do you mind if I post that (together with my idea) as an answer (community wiki if you want)?

Comment: @PhoemueX Go for it...

Comment: @PhoemueX Well, we each did half, and there's no way to post a joint answer. So one of us should post an answer and there's no reason it shouldn't be you, fine. But you might mention the name of the guy who did the other half of your post...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Sorry! Won't happen again! I also marked the post community wiki now.

Comment: @PhoemueX No problem. (I unbolded it for you - feel free to rebold it if you really think it's necessary...)

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comment, $E$ has to be a Hilbert space.

To see this, fix a linear functional $\varphi \in E'$ with $\Vert \varphi \Vert = 1$. For $z \in E$, define

$$
A_z : E \to E, x\mapsto \varphi(x) \cdot z.
$$

It is not hard to see that $E \to B(E), z \mapsto A_z$ is linear and isometric. Thus, if $B(E) = H$ is a Hilbert space, we see that $E$ is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of a Hilbert space and thus a Hilbert space itself.

Now we show that $B(E)$ can not be a Hilbert space, so that $H = B(E)$ can not hold (as an isometric isomorphism).

EDIT: The idea for this part of the proof is due to @David C. Ullrich, see the comments to the question.

For this, let us assume $\dim(H) > 1$ (otherwise, the claim is trivially true, since $H \cong \Bbb{C} \cong B(\Bbb{C})$). Thus, there are $x,y \in H$ with $x \perp y$ and $\Vert x \Vert = 1 = \Vert y \Vert$. Let $H_1 := {\rm span}(x,y)$ and $H_2 := H_1^\perp$. Let $A,B$ be the bounded operators given in matrix notation (with respect to $H= \langle x \rangle \oplus \langle y \rangle \oplus H_2$) by
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\
 & 0\\
 &  & 0
\end{matrix}\right),B=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\
 & 1\\
 &  & 0
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Put differently, $A = \pi_1$ is the orthogonal projection onto ${\rm span}(x)$ and likewise $B = \pi_2$ is the orthogonal projection onto ${\rm span}(y)$. Since $A+B$ is the orthogonal projection onto $H_1$, we get
$$
\Vert A\Vert = \Vert B \Vert = \Vert A+B\Vert =1.
$$
It is also not hard to see $\Vert A - B\Vert = 1$.

But this  is incompatible with the parallelogram identity
$$
\Vert x + y\Vert^2 + \Vert x-y \Vert^2 = 2 (\Vert x \Vert^2 + \Vert y \Vert^2),
$$
since the left-hand side would yield $2$, while the right-hand side would yield $4$ with $x=A,y=B$.

Answer (score 2):

I know a very special case, and I guess it is extensible.

Suppose that $H$ is Hilbert space such that $H\cong (H_1\hat{\otimes}(H_2)^*)^*$, where $\hat{\otimes}$ is projective tensor product, and $H_1,H_2$ is some Hilbert spaces.
For any Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, always $\mathcal{H}^{**}=\mathcal{H}$. Also for two Banach space $E,F$ always $B(E,F^*)\cong (E\hat{\otimes} F)^*$. Hence

$$H=(H_1\hat{\otimes} (H_2)^*)^*=B(H_1,(H_2)^{**})=B(H_1,H_2)$$
So if $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space such that $H=(\mathcal{H}\hat\otimes(\mathcal{H})^*)^*$, then $H=B(\mathcal{H})$.

Comment: The projective tensor product of Hilbert spaces (of dimension $>1$) is never a Hilbert space.  It is not true that $L^2(Y\times Y)=L^2(Y)\hat{\otimes}L^2(Y)$; this is only true if you replace the projective tensor product by the Hilbert space tensor product.

Comment: Yeah! its wrong and I removed it. Also I don't know if $\bar\otimes$ shows that Hilbert space tensor product, then $B(H_1,H_2^*)\cong (H_1\bar\otimes H_2)^*$ is true or not?--------------------------------------------------- But  $L^2(Y\times Y)\cong L^2(Y)\bar\otimes L^2(Y)$, is true.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, the answer is always yes.  More generally, given any Banach algebra $A$, let $\tilde{A}=A\oplus \mathbb{C}$ be its unitization (with norm $\|(a,z)\|=\|a\|+|z|$).  Given $a\in A$, let $L_a\in B(\tilde{A})$ be left multiplication by $a$.  Then $a\mapsto L_a$ is an isometric isomorphism from $A$ to a subalgebra of $B(\tilde{A})$.  (Adjoining a unit is necessary because otherwise $\|L_a\|$ might be smaller than $\|a\|$.)