# Is there any inner product on $M_{n \times n}$ inducing this norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

The set $M_{n \times n}$ is the collection of all $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

**Definition:**
$\|A\|_2=\sup_{\|u\|_2=1} \|Au\|_2$.

Is there any inner product on $M_{n \times n}$ inducing this norm?

Comment: For $n>1$, there is no such inner product, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375726/which-hilbert-space-is-isometrically-isomorphism-with-be-for-some-banach-spa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment above indicates, there is no such inner product.  One can deduce that this is the case by noting that the parallelogram identity fails to hold.